# Pluperfect and simple past

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-simple

I'm trying to talk about a person like this:

> He had come prepared for the video.

> He came prepared for the video.

Now the thing is that we say that pluperfect is used to talk about an event that happened before another one.
If I were with the person that I'm talking about while recording the video, I believe that simple past would be the right choice. But, I'm trying to talk about a person in the video, that was prepared for the video (In this sentence, it's exactly the same; should I say, `I'm trying to talk about a person in the video that was/had been prepared or came/had come prepared.`
Which one is the right choice?

Comment: It's not really possible to answer this yet.  The pluperfect is used to talk about events that occurred prior to the time you are talking about in the rest of the paragraph.  If you are talking about the time when you watched a video then it would be valid to use "had come"  If you are talking about the man in the video (and so you are talking about the time when the video was made) you would probably only need simple past.  But to judge if the pluperfect is required, optional or wrong, I'd need to see the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: "When I watched X's interview in the video, it was obvious that he _had come_ prepared, because he had all the facts and figures at his fingertips." Is this the sort of sentence you are thinking of? The pluperfect/past perfect is used because his coming happened before the video was made.

Comment: @JamesK Hello and thanks for that. Would `He came prepared for the video.` and `He had come prepared for the video.` be both correct if we're talking about the time that the video was created? Supposing that the recorder is telling another person about that person's preparation... How would these two sound? It's also not from a video or something, I came up with this sentence to ask how these two would be different...

Comment: @KateBunting Hello! Thank you! Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was trying to look for an event that happened before the video to see how pluperfect is being used here, although pluperfect sounded like the right option to my ear. Thank you!